# regex exclude img where src="//"

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

Can someone help me out, I'm poor with regex. I've got this regex to run a preg_replace on relative URL's, prepending the domain to the beginning and making them absolute. It works well for standard URL's, but I'm running into URL's that are like this:

`<img src="//domain.com/file.jpg">` 
.

..which matches the regex and is then becoming something like:

`<img src="http://www.newdomain.com//domain.com/file.jpg">`, which obviously breaks.

How can I modify this regex to not accept strings that begin with two slashes '//'?

```
preg_replace("#(<\s*img\s+[^>]*src\s*=\s*[\"'])(?!http)([^\"'>]+)([\"'>]+)#", '$1' .$url. '/$2$3', $html);
```

Comment: Use a DOM parser.  Your solution will break as soon as you encounter valid HTML tags that don't match your assumptions of how <img> tags should be sent.

Comment: have a favourite PHP parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already are excluding URLs that have "http", you can add "//" to that -

```
(<\s*img\s+[^>]*src\s*=\s*[\"'])(?!(http)|(\/\/))([^\"'>]+)([\"'>]+)
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Modified here
```

You can test it [here](http://regex101.com/r/pG3dQ6)